# Processing paths that start with a dot using Mason dhandler

Tags: apache, perl, mason

How can I make a Mason `dhandler` process a URL whose path section starts with `.`?

For example, if I have a `dhandler` file in my web root, the `dhandler` is triggered if I navigate to

```
`http://www.example.com/hello`
```

but I get a 404 if I navigate to `http://www.example.com/.hello`.

I am using `Mason` in combination with `Apache` and I have verified that this is not an `Apache` configuration issue forbidding paths that start with dot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably mean [HTML::Mason](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Mason) and not the new(er) [Mason](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mason).

While I haven't installed Apache, but it is simple to create an PSGI test-case using [HTML::Mason::PSGIHandler](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Mason::PSGIHandler), like such `app.psgi`

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use HTML::Mason::PSGIHandler;

my $h = HTML::Mason::PSGIHandler->new(
    comp_root => $ENV{HOME}.'/tmp/mas/comps',
);

my $app = sub {
    my $env = shift;
    $h->handle_psgi($env);
};
```

and an very simple `dhandler`

```
<pre>
=<% $m->dhandler_arg %>=
</pre>
```

after running `plackup` and pointing my browser to http://localhost:5000/.hello it shows

[image]

so, the [HTML::Mason](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Mason) **hasn't** any limitations on processing paths with dots.

If you need more help, edit your question and add relevant parts of your apache config, htaccess, and your handlers how do you invoke the [HTML::Mason](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Mason).